# Parse JSON Array Objetct into PHP script

Tags: php, android, arrays, json

A have to send  this Json Array  from Android to a php script. In this case I've send this json with 1 element ('CABECERA') and in my php script  I don't know how to parse  to work with.

**How I have to do to re-create an entire CABECERA object from this json?.**

```
 $_jsone_str= [ {\"CABECERA\":[{\"CustomerID\":\"1\",\"datetime\":\"\",\"fecha\":\"150303122830\",\"idadmin\":\"3\",\"idcli\":\"4\",\"msj\":\"\",\"nroped\":\"\",\"orderId\":\"1\",\"puntoVentaID\":\"AMALGAME\",\"status\":\"0\",\"total\":\"0.0\"}]}]

$json = json_decode($_jsone_str);

foreach ( $json ->CABECERA as $decode ){
   print_r($decode);
}
```

How supose to parse this json array 
what I do wrong?

Comment: It's [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) what you are looking? | PHP >= 5.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do is the following:

1. I first check if POST JSON with POST HEADER **POST** exists:

   ```
   if( isset($_POST["POST"]) ) {

   }
   ```
2. I deallocate the JSON file:

   ```
   $data = $_POST["JSON"];
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $jsonDecoded = json_decode($data);
   ```
3. I then parse the JSON data:

   ```
   foreach ($jsonDecoded->**"object/array name"** as $object) {

   }
   ```

In your case, **"object/array name"** happens to be **CABECERA**

Full code:

```
if( isset($_POST["JSON"]) ) {

    $data = $_POST["JSON"];
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $jsonDecoded = json_decode($data);

    foreach ($jsonDecoded->**"object/array name"** as $object) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The json array must be a string.

And the function json_decode($data, true) - Lookup for the second paremeter, it will return the parsed json in associative arrays else it will be as object.

```
    $json = "[ {\"CABECERA\":[{\"CustomerID\":\"1\",\"datetime\":\"\",\"fecha\":\"150303122830\",\"idadmin\":\"3\",\"idcli\":\"4\",\"msj\":\"\",\"nroped\":\"\",\"orderId\":\"1\",\"puntoVentaID\":\"AMALGAME\",\"status\":\"0\",\"total\":\"0.0\"}]}]";

foreach ( json_decode($json, true) as $decode ){
   print_r($decode);
}
```

Comment: I just did a test on the code and it worked.

What is your php version?

Comment: How I have to do to re-create an entire CABECERA object from this json?.

Comment: You must parse the string with json_decode(), if your php version is lower than 5.2 then you must lookup for some 3rd partie json parser or create one.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure JSON to be decoded is a string:

```
$_jsone_str= "[ {\"CABECERA\":[{\"CustomerID\":\"1\",\"datetime\":\"\",\"fecha\":\"150303122830\",\"idadmin\":\"3\",\"idcli\":\"4\",\"msj\":\"\",\"nroped\":\"\",\"orderId\":\"1\",\"puntoVentaID\":\"AMALGAME\",\"status\":\"0\",\"total\":\"0.0\"}]}]";

$json = json_decode($_jsone_str);
```

Check the result:

```
print_r($json);
```

Call it the right way:

```
foreach ( $json as $decode ){
   print_r($decode->CABECERA);
}
```